# How can I export a large zone from OpenStreetMap?

Tags: export

I would like to export San Francisco in OSM so I can use it in Blender.
The problem is that the zone is too big for OpenStreetMap so I have an error each time...

Do I have another way to export the whole city?

Comment: What data do you want? Roads, buildings, land layers? What does "too big for Openstreetmap" mean? The whole world is in Openstreetmap. Is it just too big for your (unspecified) "export" procedure?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/271768/113585). It covers a number of options for downloading large areas of OSM data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use http://extract.bbbike.org/ and choose your area of interest. The export format can be Shapefile or OSM XML. Maybe you have to post process the data.

A other way is openstreetmap.org for SVG or Raster Export:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can download all of the OSM data for California here: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/california.html

Data from this source is usually updated daily.

Is there a specific file format that you would prefer?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to use this payable [service](https://data.nextgis.com/en/) to download OSM data in different formats: shapefile, ArcGIS file geodatabase, geoJSON, TAB, MIF/MID, PDF, CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a raster, you should try SASPlanet: https://bitbucket.org/sas_team/sas.planet.bin/downloads/

[image]

Is OpenSource and portable (for Windows) and there are many tutorials in YouTube.